# Link the heights of the rows of two listview

Tags: wpf

I have a custom control that has two listViews employing GridViewRowPresenters. I need the row heights of the two listViews to be the same. The catch is I wont know what the heights will be until run time.

That is, both will have their heights set to Auto and when the control is rendered one listView will have its rows at ActualHeight = 30 the other at ActualHeight = 40. I want them both to be 40.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ListViews use a shared item template, all you would have to do is wrap your GridViewRowPresenter in a grid and then use a SharedSizeGroup on that grid's only row. Here's how it can be achieved.

**XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="300"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <GridViewColumnCollection x:Key="GridViewColumns">
            <GridViewColumn Width="100"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Text}"
                            Header="Text" />
        </GridViewColumnCollection>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="RowTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="RowSizeGroup" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                    <GridViewRowPresenter Columns="{StaticResource GridViewColumns}" />
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter Columns="{StaticResource GridViewColumns}" />
        <ListView Grid.Row="1"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RowTemplate}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items1}" />
        <ListView Grid.Row="2"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RowTemplate}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items2}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Code-Behind (for reference, but not really important)**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl2.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl2
    {
        public UserControl2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            Items1 = new ObservableCollection<object>
                {
                    new Item {Text = "Hello World!"},
                    new Item {Text = "Hello \nWorld!"}
                };
            Items2 = new ObservableCollection<object>
                {
                    new Item {Text = "Testing 1\n2\n3"}
                };
        }

        private class Item
        {
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<object> Items1 { get; private set; }

        public ObservableCollection<object> Items2 { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

If you want to set the height of your rows explicitly, just replace `<RowDefinition Height="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="RowSizeGroup" />` with `<RowDefinition Height="40" SharedSizeGroup="RowSizeGroup" />` where 40 in this case is the specific height.